# Javascript Promises: TypeError: Cannot read property 'then' of undefined

Tags: javascript, reactjs, promise

I'm trying to make `getVideos()` asynchronous, then call and use the result of its axios call in the function `filterVideos`. However, these promises are giving me problems.

`getVideos`

```
getVideos() {
    let myFirstPromise = new Promise((resolve) => {
      const url = process.env.REACT_APP_MIDDLEWARE_URL + "/api/videolist";
      const options = {
        headers: {
          Authorization: "Bearer " + localStorage.getItem("userToken"),
        },
      };
      axios.get(url, options).then(
        (res) => {
          this.setState({
            video: res.data.videos[0],
            videos: res.data.videos,
          });
          console.log(this.state.videos);
          resolve(res);
        },
        (error) => {
          if (error.response.status === 401) {
            this.props.signOut();
          }
        }
      );
    });
  }
```

`filterVideos`

```
filterVideos() {
    let completed = true;
    this.getVideos().then((res) => {
      res.forEach((video) => {
        if (video.status != "COMPLETED") {
          completed = false;
        }
      });
    });
    if (completed === false) {
      this.waitForCompleted();
    }
  }
```

Comment: you are not returning anything in `getVideos`

Comment: also, since `axios.get` returns a Promise, you don't need to wrap that code in a `new Promise` - so remove `let myFirstPromise = new Promise((resolve) => {`, and the second last line in getVideos, i.e. `});` and then `return axios.get....`

Comment: note, once you fix that, you'll have an issue that `completed` won't ever be false, since `getVideos` does things asynchronously - you'll need that code inside the `.then` in filterVideos

Comment: that fixed it! Thanks!